# What is this black worm-like creature with a yellow underbelly

Tags: species-identification, zoology, molluscs

This was found in the Malay Peninsula around noon. Unfortunately it was doused in hot water by my grandmother.
Image below is after having been killed by hot water.
[image: After getting killed by hot water]

It is about 1.5cm-ish long. It was curled up for some time but it started to move when it was exposed to sunlight(before it was killed). According to my grandmother, she had seen these long ago and they would stick on trees and foam up when touched. It didn't seem to foam up after it was killed though.

What species is this and is it endangered?
Edit : I'm very sure it is a type of chiton now and that it has already been doccumented. I'm saying this because I saw a video on YouTube with an extremely similar creature. Although I am still not sure what species it is.

Comment: Any chance you have a photo of the other side. It looks to be a slug or perhaps a flatworm of some sort.

Comment: No, I did not take a picture of the other side unfortunately.